# What is the remainder for a taylor series of two variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I know that for a function of one variable $f(x)$, the Taylor expansion is $$f(x)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+...+\frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n+R_n(x,x_0) $$
where 
\begin{align*}
R_n(x,x_0)&=\int^x_{x_0}\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!} f^{(n+1)}(t)dt \\
&=f^{(n+1)}(\xi)\int^x_{x_0} \frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt \\
&=f^{(n+1)}(\xi) \frac{(x-x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.
\end{align*}

My question is for $f(x,y)$ with a Taylor expansion
$$f(x)=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)+...+R_n(x,x_0,y,y_0) $$ 
What is $R_n(x,x_0,y,y_0)$?

Comment: Not sure, but it's suppose to be the $n+1$ term evaluated at some point $(t,k)$ such that $x_0 < t < x, y_0 < k < y$

Comment: I do not know if you have seen this but it may be of some help.

https://sites.math.washington.edu/~folland/Math425/taylor2.pdf

Comment: Yes I have seen it but I am confused. I have no idea on how to apply what it says to something like $x^y$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We consider  $x,x_0,y,y_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and define intervals $I,J$ with
\begin{align*}
&I=[\mathrm{min}(x,x_0),\mathrm{max}(x,x_0)]\qquad\text{and}\qquad  J=[\mathrm{min}(y,y_0),\mathrm{max}(y,y_0)]
\end{align*}

> Let  $f:I\times  J\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an $(n+1)$-times continuously differentiable function in $x$  and $y$. There exist values   $\xi\in I^\circ,\eta\in  J^\circ$, so that following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x,y)&=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{2}\left(f_{xx}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)^2+2f_{xy}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)(y-y_0)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\left.+f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)^2\right)\\
> &\qquad\,\,\,\vdots\\
> &\qquad+\frac{1}{n!}\left(f_{x^n}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)^n+\binom{n}{1}f_{x^{n-1}y}(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)^{n-1}(y-y_0)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\cdots+f_{y^n}(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)^n\Big)\\
> &\qquad+R_n(x,y)
> \end{align*}
>   The *[Lagrange remainder](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeRemainder.html)* term $R_n(x,y)$  is given as
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{R_n(x,y)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(f_{x^{n+1}}(\xi,\eta)(x-x_0)^{n+1}+\binom{n+1}{1}f_{x^{n-1}y}(\xi,\eta)(x-x_0)^n(y-y_0)\right.}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\color{blue}{+\cdots+f_{y^{n+1}}(\xi,\eta)(y-y_0)^{n+1}\Big)}
> \end{align*}

A more compact notation can be given with the  *[total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative)*. We obtain
\begin{align*}
df&=(x-x_0)f_x+(y-y_0)f_y,\\
d^2f&=((x-x_0)f_x+(y-y_0)f_y)^{(2)}\\
&=((x-x_0)^2f_{xx}+2 (x-x_0)(y-y_0)  f_{xy}+(y-y_0)^2f_{yy}\\
&\,\,\,\vdots\\
d^nf&=((x-x_0)f_x+(y-y_0)f_y)^{(n)}\\
&=(x-x_0)^nf_{x^n}+\binom{n}{1}(x-x_0)^{n-1}(y-y_0)f_{x^{n-1}y}\\
&\qquad+\cdots+(y-y_0)^nf_{y^n}
\end{align*}

> and we can  write
>   \begin{align*}
> f(x,y)=f(x_0,y_0)+df(x_0,y_0)+\frac{1}{2}d^2f(x_0,y_0)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}d^nf(x_0,y_0)+R_n(x,y)
> \end{align*}
>   with
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{R_n(x,y)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}d^{n+1}f(\xi,\eta)}
> \end{align*}

*Note:*  A  derivation  similar to this answer can be found in section 6.3  of  [Introduction to Calculus and Analysis II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FC6SGAI) by Richard Courant.

Comment: Just so that I fully understand, the remainder for a Taylor series up to 2nd order, $R_2(x,y)$ is
\begin{align}
R_2(x,y)&=\frac{1}{3!}(f_{x^3}(\xi,\eta)(x-x_0)^3 \\
&+3f_{x^2y}(\xi,\eta)(x-x_0)^2(y-y_0)+3f_{xy^2}(\xi,\eta)(x-x_0)(y-y_0)^2\\
&+f_{y^3}(\xi,\eta)(y-y_0)^3)
\end{align}

Comment: @AzJ: Sorry, I've misread your comment. Yes, you're right. The *Taylor  series* has terms up to the 2nd order, implying the remainder term shows derivations of 3rd  order.

Comment: @AzJ: Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-)