# My question is about the Taylor formula of $f(x,y)=\sin x\sin y$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have to solve the following exercise:

Find the secondary approach of $f(x,y)=\sin x\sin y$ near the point $(0,0)$. How accurate is the approach if $|x|\leq 0{,}1$ and $|y|\leq0{,}1$?

(I have to prove that $|E|\leq {\frac{8}{6}}(0{,}1)^3$ )

$-$ I found :

the secondary approach is for $n=2$

\begin{align}f(x,y)= &f(0,0)+xf_x+yf_y+\frac{1}{2}(x^2f_{xx}+2xyf_{xy}+y^2f_{yy})\\&+ \frac{1}{6}(x^3f_{xxx}+3x^2yf_{xxy} +3y^2xf_{xyy}+y^3f_{yyy})(φ,n)\end{align}

$f(0,0)=0$

$f_x(0,0)=\cos0\sin0=0$, $f_y(0,0)=\sin0\cos0=0$

$f_{xx}(0,0)=-\sin 0\sin0=0$, $f_{yy}(0,0)=-\sin0\sin0=0$

$f_{xy}(0,0)=\cos0\cos0=1$

therefore $f(x,y)\simeq 0+0+0+\frac{1}{2}(x^20+2xy+y^20)=xy$,

the error estimation is $|E(x,y)|=\frac{1}{6}(x^3f_{xxx}+\dots+y^3f_{yyy})(φ,n)$

$-$How am I going to prove that $|E|\leq \frac{8}{6}(0{,}1)^3?$ I don't know what I have to do. Are the things that I've done above correct?

Comment: You can use [Lagrange's form of the remainder, as it looks for several variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2443435/578878). The derivatives that appear therein evaluated at unknown points are nevertheless sines and cosines, which have uniform bounds, $1$.

Comment: This particular problem has the simplifying feature that the function is factorial, $f(x,y)=g_1(x)g_2(y)$. Therefore, you could deduce the bound from [Lagrange's remainder for one variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) applied to $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(y)$ separately.

Comment: To continue on the path you delineate in your question (since, pace some comments above, the first question here is **not** to imagine other approaches), simply note that every third derivative involved in your last formula for $E$ is at most $1$, that the prefactors $x^iy^j$ involved are all bounded by $0.1^3$ and that the prefactor $\frac16$ then yields exactly the bound $\frac16\cdot8\cdot0.1^3$ you have been asked to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that in $0{,}1$, the comma is a decimal comma.

Observe that all partial derivatives at any order are the products of a sine or a cosine in $x$ and a sine or a cosine in $y$, up to a $-$ sign. So the absolute  value of these derivatives are bounded  by $1$, and by the triangle inequality,
$$|E(x,y)|=\frac{1}{6}|(x^3f_{xxx}+\dots+y^3f_{yyy})(φ,n)|\le \frac{1}{6}|(|x|^3 +3x^2|y|+3|x|y^2+|y|^3)$$
which is no more than $\;\dfrac{1}{6}(0.1+0.1)^3=\dfrac8610^{-3}\;$ on $\;[-0.1,0.1]\times[-0.1,0.1]$.